# How to trend a photo album with photos inside it, trending algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm building a photo album sharing site. Every photo album can have only have a maxmimum of 2 photos inside it. The table structure is given below.

```
Photo_album: There can be maximum of two photos inside each photo album
------------------------
id
name
date_created
likes

Photos: This table is to store photos for a photo album, so there is album_id column to reference to Photo_album table
------------------------
id
album_id
name
date_created
likes
```

I want to trend photos, so the algorithm i have for trending photos is like given  below

```
Algorithm to trend individual photo:
score = total likes of photos / weighted age of 2 photos
```

I also want to trend every album. Taking the example algorithm above for trending photos, i can trend Photo albums using this algorithm;

```
score = total likes of photo-album / age of photoalbum
```

Now, i'm not sure if the following algorithm is the right one to trend Photo album; check this

```
score = total likes of photoalbum+photos / weighted age of photos+photoalbum
```

I wanna make new photo albums with recent likes have higher score or say, to have them appear in higher level and make the older photo albums to go lower.

I need some inputs/ideas/ways to implement from anyone who has done something similar to this. I'm going to implement this in PHP.

Comment: trend detection is not as simple as you think. Here is an example for Hacker News ranking algorithm: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574

Comment: Another approach could take into consideration the time of the "likes" as well, and not only their counts. Bottom line: this is complicated and domain specific. You will need to try a bunch of things, think what's wrong with it, try something new - until you are satisfied. Also google to see what others have done to get ideas, but bottom line - there is no single answer for this question.

Comment: thanks for the link above. I'll go through it and see now. Also, i found another interesting point of discussion link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509563/trending-algorithm